# How do you parse the bin file from INT8 Calibration of TensorRT?

Tags: python-3.x, nvidia, tensorrt

I have created a python script for calibrating(INT8) the dynamic scales of the activation of TinyYOLO V2 using TensorRT. The script gave me a file called calibration_cache.bin. How do I parse the .bin file ? What do the values inside the .bin file mean ?

**calibrator.py**

```py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import ctypes
import tensorrt as trt
import os

CHANNEL = 3
HEIGHT = 416
WIDTH = 416

class PythonEntropyCalibrator(trt.IInt8EntropyCalibrator):
  def __init__(self, input_layers, stream):
    trt.IInt8EntropyCalibrator.__init__(self)
    self.input_layers = input_layers
    self.stream = stream
    self.d_input = cuda.mem_alloc(self.stream.calibration_data.nbytes)
    stream.reset()

  def get_batch_size(self):
    return self.stream.batch_size

  def get_batch(self, bindings, names):
    batch = self.stream.next_batch()
    if not batch.size:
      return None

    cuda.memcpy_htod(self.d_input, batch)
    for i in self.input_layers[0]:
      assert names[0] != i

    bindings[0] = int(self.d_input)
    return bindings

  def read_calibration_cache(self, length=0):
    if os.path.exists('calibration_cache.bin'):
      with open('calibration_cache.bin', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
    return None

  def write_calibration_cache(self, cache, size=0):
    with open('calibration_cache.bin', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(cache)
    return None

class ImageBatchStream():
  def __init__(self, batch_size, calibration_files, preprocessor):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.max_batches = (len(calibration_files) // batch_size) + \
                       (1 if (len(calibration_files) % batch_size) \
                        else 0)
    self.files = calibration_files
    self.calibration_data = np.zeros((batch_size, CHANNEL, HEIGHT, WIDTH), \
                                     dtype=np.float32)
    self.batch = 0
    self.preprocessor = preprocessor

  @staticmethod
  def read_image_chw(path):
    img = Image.open(path).resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT), Image.NEAREST)
    im = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
    im = im[:,:,::-1]
    im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
    return im

  def reset(self):
    self.batch = 0

  def next_batch(self):
    if self.batch < self.max_batches:
      imgs = []
      files_for_batch = self.files[self.batch_size * self.batch : \
                        self.batch_size * (self.batch + 1)]
      for f in files_for_batch:
                        self.batch_size * (self.batch + 1)]
      for f in files_for_batch:
        print("[ImageBatchStream] Processing ", f)
        img = ImageBatchStream.read_image_chw(f)
        img = self.preprocessor(img)
        imgs.append(img)
      for i in range(len(imgs)):
        self.calibration_data[i] = imgs[i]
      self.batch += 1
      return np.ascontiguousarray(self.calibration_data, dtype=np.float32)
    else:
      return np.array([])
```

**test.py**

```py
from random import shuffle
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import tensorrt as trt
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import os
from calibrator import *

TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.WARNING)

model_file = './tiny_yolov2/Model.onnx'
dataset_loc = './Dataset/*.jpg'

def normalize(data):
        data /= 255.0
        return data

def create_calibration_dataset():
        calibration_files = glob.glob(dataset_loc)
        shuffle(calibration_files)
        return calibration_files[:20]

calibration_files = create_calibration_dataset()

NUM_IMAGES_PER_BATCH = 5

batchstream = ImageBatchStream(NUM_IMAGES_PER_BATCH, calibration_files, normalize)

Int8_calibrator =  PythonEntropyCalibrator(["conv2d_91_input"], batchstream)

builder = trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER)
builder.int8_calibrator = Int8_calibrator
builder.refittable = True
builder.int8_mode = True
network = builder.create_network()
parser = trt.OnnxParser(network, TRT_LOGGER)
print(builder.int8_mode, builder.platform_has_fast_int8,builder.refittable)
with open(model_file, 'rb') as model:
        parser.parse(model.read())
print('Done reading ONNX File\n')
engine = builder.build_cuda_engine(network)
print(engine, TRT_LOGGER)
with open("model.trt", "wb") as f:
        f.write(engine.serialize())
print("Done converting the ONNX to TRT\n")
tinyolo_fitter = trt.Refitter(engine, TRT_LOGGER)
print(tinyolo_fitter.refit_cuda_engine())
print(tinyolo_fitter.get_tensors_with_dynamic_range())
```

**calibration_cache.bin**

```
TRT-5105-EntropyCalibration
image: 3c010a14
scalerPreprocessor_scaled: 38018ba0
image2: 38018ba0
batchnormalization_1_output: 3d07b31d
leakyrelu_1_output: 3c98a317
maxpooling2d_1_output: 3c1e5b30
batchnormalization_2_output: 3ca6aa67
leakyrelu_2_output: 3ca6aa67
maxpooling2d_2_output: 3c82cf7d
batchnormalization_3_output: 3ce07ce8
leakyrelu_3_output: 3ce52236
maxpooling2d_3_output: 3cc8ed6f
batchnormalization_4_output: 3d3df55f
leakyrelu_4_output: 3c651727
maxpooling2d_4_output: 3cec84fc
batchnormalization_5_output: 3d0f51e3
leakyrelu_5_output: 3cb52377
maxpooling2d_5_output: 3d026049
batchnormalization_6_output: 3d387291
leakyrelu_6_output: 3ccc009a
maxpooling2d_6_output: 3c8d0f0c
batchnormalization_7_output: 3e0de3d2
leakyrelu_7_output: 3d7b4397
batchnormalization_8_output: 3cc459d6
leakyrelu_8_output: 3cbd9562
grid: 3ddc32dc
```

Comment: calibration_cache.bin contains individual layer's scaling factors of double datatype in hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_calibration_cache(self, length=0):
if os.path.exists('calibration_cache.bin'):
  with open('calibration_cache.bin', 'rb') as f:
    return f.read()
return None
```

This does the work i guess. If there is a calibration_cache.bin file in your dir, calibrator parses it instead of calibrating again.